# Does scikit-learn fit() modify original data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, regression, training-data

In scikit-learn, does fit() modify the original data?

I think I saw some code attaching a copy() call to the original data:

```
regressor.fit(x.copy(), y.copy())
```

This is important to me as I wish to train a set of data multiple times.

Comment: it doesn't. the code use some tricks to make the train faster but will not modify your datas when you call it.

Comment: great. knowing this now i can lump more data into the memory.

Comment: the regressor you were looking at might have been a pipline with some prepocessing and then your datas are indeed modified.

Comment: It is auto-sklearn which is largely based on scikit-learn: https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/examples/example_crossvalidation.html#sphx-glr-examples-example-crossvalidation-py